# Configuring Xdebug debugger on PhpStorm w/ Laravel, Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, xdebug

Trying to configure my Vagrant server to use Xdebug. Read that it comes with Xdebug, but I checked this and doesn't seem to be true.

SSH into Vagrant machine,

```
$ php -v
```

reveals that machine is using

```
PHP 7.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2017 13:58:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies with blackfire v1.18.0~linux-x64-non_zts72, https://blackfire.io, by SensioLabs
```

No xdebug. So I tried installing xdebug with

```
$ brew install homebrew/php/php72-xdebug
```

Seemed to work. But then I tried finding the path to xdebug.so:

```
$ locate xdebug.so

/usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so 
/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so 
/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
```

Tried putting all of these into php.ini, and they all failed. 
Tried installing via

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-xdebug 
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-xdebug
```

So, I searched, and found:

```
$ apt search xdebug
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
php-xdebug/xenial,now 2.5.5-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed] Xdebug Module for PHP
```

What am I doing wrong to get Xdebug and php configured on my remote machine?

Comment: chcek if xdebug is correctly configured on php side (/etc/php?/conf.d/xdebug.ini or similar).

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand. On the virtual machine, I have 4 xdebug.ini files, but they are each in  `/etc/php/(versionHere)/mods-available/xdebug.ini`. In my normal terminal, I see that I am using PHP 7.1 with Xdebug 2.5.5.

Comment: Update: using pecl, I was able to install xdebug on virtual machine. Now when I run `php -v` it shows xdebug 2.6.0. Progress.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing with Postman using the mapped domain.. Using the actual server IP works.

So, instead of "restfulapi.dev", hit "128.153.123.21" or whatever it is.

Very silly.